# Replace every line in a file, one by one, with python

Tags: python, file, overwrite

**QUESTION:** *HOW OVERWRITE A LINE IN A FILE AFTER READING THE LINE?*

By NOT making a new file, or reading the hole file, since the file has 123.500 lines.

```
for line in source:

    newline = "+" + line

    #write over the line in the file with newline
```

line = "HAHA",
newline = "+HAHA"

How can i replace the newline with the line, in the file?

Comment: and the problem is ... ?

Comment: there are lots of other things going on in your source code, and what is your question again?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either

- write to a different file, line by line, or
- read the whole file in memory and replace the original with a new file you write.

The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module can assist you with this, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9308129/222914)